# Does Kafka provides Producer level offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, kafka-producer-api, producer

Suppose , I've got multiple Kafka producers producing data simultaneously to a single Kafka Topic.

Is it possible to get which was the last offset produced by a given producer ?

For example :

Producers : `P1 , P2`

Topic : `T1` with one partition `Partition-0`

`P1` published 100 records and `P2`  published 150 records.

I want to find out offset of the last record published by P1 and P2 respectively.

Note that, I'm not asking for global Topic-Partition offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kafka brokers don't track that information.

Only the producers have that information but it's not even part of their built-in metrics. If you want to track the last offset per producer you will need to create a metric in each of your producer instances yourself.

You can simply retrieve the [offset](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/RecordMetadata.html#offset--) in the `RecordMetadata` object returned by `send()` and expose it as a metric for example.

Comment: By metric , do you mean utilizing http://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#metrics--    <--- this API ?

Comment: No, I meant create your own metrics